# How to stream smoothly from flask yolov8 to reactjs frontend

Tags: reactjs, flask, video-streaming, yolov8, ultralytics

I'm new to this project and I'm facing challenges with streaming the video processed by YOLOv8 on my frontend. Currently, the video playback is extremely slow, running at around 1 frame per second. I'm eager to optimize the streaming for smoother playback. Can anyone advise on the best strategies or technologies to achieve this? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.